# Move certain nodes that are sibling of select node into a new parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

I did some searching here and found some questions that were related to my problem, but I'm still having trouble...(hope it's ok that I'm adding a new question instead of commenting on an existing one..)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<section>
    <title>Main Section</title>
    <para>Here is some text that is a child of a main section.</para>
    <para>Some more text.</para>
    <para>When a section has subsections, it should not have loose paragraphs before the first sub section. Those loose paras should be placed inside a comment element.</para>
    <section>
        <title>This is my subsection</title>
        <para>Text that is inside of the sub-section</para>
        <para>And some more sub section text.</para>
    </section>
</section>
```

I want to have the /section/para placed inside a newly created comment node, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<section>
    <title>Main Section</title>
    <comment>
       <para>Here is some text that is a child of a main section.</para>
       <para>Some more text.</para>
       <para>When a section has subsections, it should not have loose paragraphs before the first sub section. Those loose paras should be placed inside a comment element.</para>
    </comment>
    <section>
        <title>This is my subsection</title>
        <para>Text that is inside of the sub-section</para>
        <para>And some more sub section text.</para>
    </section>
</section>
```

I tried some of the suggestions I found searching stackoverflow, the closest one is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632244/move-certain-child-nodes-down-to-a-new-grandchild-level)

This is the stylesheet I'm using:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>


<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!-- paras that are children of a section that has direct para children and dircect section children -->
<xsl:template match="section[para][section]/para[1]">
    <comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../para" mode="commentPara"/>

    </comment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="commentPara">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[para][section]/para"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's outputting this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<section>
    <title>Main Section</title>



    <section>
        <title>This is my subsection</title>
        <para>Text that is inside of the sub-section</para>
        <para>And some more sub section text.</para>
    </section>
</section>
```

simply deleting the paras I want to wrap in a comment tag. I tried going essentially line by line through the stylesheet in the question I linked to...any ideas?
thanks, 
bp

Comment: Dear badperson, This is a good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, simple, short and easy solution that may also be more efficient than other solutions, not using keys. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's grouping adjacents `para` elements.

The problem is in [Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict): because both `para` matching rules have the same import precedence and the same calculated priority, error recovery mechanism could lead to apply last one.

You need to explicitly define a `@priority` on the "first `para` child" rule like:

```
<xsl:template match="section[para][section]/para[1]" priority="1">
</
```

With such modification, the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<section>
    <title>Main Section</title>
    <comment>
        <para>Here is some text that is a child of a main section.</para>
        <para>Some more text.</para>
        <para>When a section has subsections, it should not have loose paragraphs before the first sub section. Those loose paras should be placed inside a comment element.</para>
    </comment>
    <section>
        <title>This is my subsection</title>
        <para>Text that is inside of the sub-section</para>
        <para>And some more sub section text.</para>
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I would do it this way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPreceding" match="para"
  use="generate-id(following-sibling::section[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section[preceding-sibling::para]">
  <comment>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
        select="key('kPreceding', generate-id())"/>
  </comment>

  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "para[following-sibling::section]"/>

 <xsl:template match="para" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<section>
    <title>Main Section</title>
    <para>Here is some text that is a child of a main section.</para>
    <para>Some more text.</para>
    <para>When a section has subsections, it should not have loose paragraphs before the first sub section. Those loose paras should be placed inside a comment element.</para>
    <section>
        <title>This is my subsection</title>
        <para>Text that is inside of the sub-section</para>
        <para>And some more sub section text.</para>
    </section>
</section>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<section>
   <title>Main Section</title>
   <comment>
      <para>Here is some text that is a child of a main section.</para>
      <para>Some more text.</para>
      <para>When a section has subsections, it should not have loose paragraphs before the first sub section. Those loose paras should be placed inside a comment element.</para>
   </comment>
   <section>
      <title>This is my subsection</title>
      <para>Text that is inside of the sub-section</para>
      <para>And some more sub section text.</para>
   </section>
</section>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule (template) copies every node "as-is".
2. The overriding template for `section` that has preceding sibling(s) `para` wraps all such siblings with a `comment` element, then calls the identity transformation on itself.
3. For convenience we define a key that matches all `para` elements preceding a `section` element with a given `generate-id()`.
4. The `para` elements that have a following sibling `section` are excluded from the action of the identity rule by an overriding template, that simply does nothing.
5. Finally, such `para` elements, when being output within the wrapper `comment` are processed in mode `copy`, which simply calls the identity rule to do the copying.